# In Django is there a way to use FOO_set on a model with a foreign key that refers to objects of the same model type?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
    class Video(models.Model):
      views = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, related_name='views')
      parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)

      def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

      def _get_views_count(self):
        return self.views.count()

      def _get_comments_count(self):
        return self.comment_set.all().count()

      def _get_playlists(self):
        return self.playlist_set.all()

      views_count = property(_get_views_count)
      comments_count = property(_get_comments_count)
      playlists = property(_get_playlists)

      most_viewed_objects = MostViewedVideoManager()
      objects = models.Manager()



 class MostViewedVideoManager(models.Manager):
      def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MostViewedProjectManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(lovers=Count('views')).order_by('viewers')[:20]
```

And I want to get the set of Videos that have a given Parent. I thought I could just do something like this:

```
v = Video.objects.get(id=3)
v.video_set.all()
```

However it's throwing this error:

```
AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

    (full trace)
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in all(self)
    115 
    116     def all(self):
--> 117         return self.get_query_set()
    118 
    119     def count(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in get_query_set(self)
    421             def get_query_set(self):
    422                 db = self._db or router.db_for_read(rel_model, instance=instance)
--> 423                 return superclass.get_query_set(self).using(db).filter(**(self.core_filters))
    424 
    425             def add(self, *objs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in filter(self, *args, **kwargs)
    548         set.
    549         """
--> 550         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    551 
    552     def exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs)
    560         if args or kwargs:
    561             assert self.query.can_filter(), \
--> 562                     "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."
    563 
    564         clone = self._clone()
```

I believe it's related to the `MostViewedManager` - since taking that out resolves the issue. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: That error is not coming from that code. Please post the full code, and the real traceback. Plus, please accept some answers.

Comment: Thanks - you're right - it seems like the error is related to the manager class MostViewedVideoManager....but I'm not sure why...I've added a full trace and more code.

Comment: You're somewhere trying to filter a queryset that is returned from the `MostViewedVideoManager`...

Comment: Ok - I found that reordering the managers in my model solved the problem ...though I'm not sure why. ie. objects = models.Manger() before most_viewed_objects = MostViewedVideoManager()

Comment: The first manager listed becomes the default manager. In your case, that was your custom manager that returned the sliced queryset. When you switch them, the default became the standard manager which doesn't slice its queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you're trying to filter a queryset that has already been sliced.

Don't return a sliced queryset from a manager's `get_query_set` method. Either return it unsliced, or create a separate method that returns the sliced version.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fix your specific problem (sliced queryset), but the title of your post indicates that you don't know about the `related_name` property of `ForeignKey`.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    views  = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, related_name='views')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children')
```

Using related name allows you to query more naturally:

```
>>> video = Video.objects.get(id=1)
<Video: 1>
>>> video.children.all()
[<Video: 2>, <Video: 3>, <Video: 4>]
>>> gte2_lovers = Video.objects.annotate(lovers=count('views')).filter(lovers__gte=2)
>>> Video.objects.filter(children__in=gte2_lovers)
[<Video: 1>, <Video: 4>]
```